Intersection of a spheroid with a plane
Given the following equation for a spheroid,
$$ 
x^2 + y^2 + \frac{z^2}{k^2} = a^2  
$$
and plane,
$$
ux + vy + \frac{wz}{k^2} = a^2
$$
I need to find the parametric equations $x(t), y(t), z(t)$ for the curve that results from their intersection. It can be assumed that the plane and spheroid do indeed always intersect. Also, the spheroid is centered on the z-axis.
One approach would be to express the spheroid in spherical coordinates,
\begin{align}
x &= a \sin(\phi) \cos(\theta) \\
y &= a \sin(\phi) \sin(\theta) \\
z &= a k \cos(\phi) 
\end{align}
and then to substitute these equations into the plane equation and solve for $\phi(\theta)$. This can then be substituted back into the parametric equations to give the desired result. however, I am not sure if this is the optimal approach.
Any guidance would be appreciated!

Optimality needs to be determined. Another possibility I see is this: if you rotate the $z$ axis perpendicular to the plane, you will get the two-dimensional circle.

Scaling the $z$-axis by $k$ turns the spheroid into the sphere of radius $a$ about the origin; you can then parameterize the circle of intersection with the (transformed) plane, and finally apply the inverse transformation to this parametrization to get the desired ellipse. Does that suit your needs?
